# How to exclude method from the transaction advice?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions, aop, spring.net

I have the following declaration:

```xml
  <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>
```

I wrapped of the transactions all methods from the pointcut patterns.
But I want custom wrap one of the method. 
Does has Spring.Net functionality of the "black list" for tx:advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is "black list" functionality in the `<tx:advice ... />` tag. The transaction advice will always be applied to the matching methods.

I think the intention of the `<tx:attributes ... />` list is to specify which transaction attributes to use (depending on the name of the method) not to exclude methods from being wrapped in a transaction.

If you're only interested in applying custom *transaction properties* to a specific method, this can easily be done. For instance, if you want to set `read-only=true` instead of the default value `false` for `VerySpecificMethod`:

```xml
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
  <tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="VerySpecificMethod" read-only="true"/>
    <tx:method name="*"/>
  </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

The first matching method name will specifiy the transaction attributes to use so now, `VerySpecificMethod` will be executed within a read-only transaction. Other methods will use the default value `false`.

Comment: Thanks, I try it after holidays.

Comment: I want to call out methods Save and Get from one method, but these methods are wrapped by one transaction via AOP.  
Get calling throws exceptions because there was no transaction commit.

Comment: Then you should use the propagation attribute. Something like `<tx:method name="VerySpecificMethod" propagation="RequiresNew"/>`. Check [the docs for the available propagation attributes](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/transaction.html#tx-attributes-settings).

Comment: By default, the same transaction will be used. When saving, you should of course not use the `read-only="true"` attribute setting.

Comment: I tried to set propagation property to "RequiresNew", but without any result. I will look, thanks

Comment: Could you try `<tx:method name="NameOfWrappingMethod" propagation="Never"/>`?